# Paste DataObject into Word C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I'm trying to paste data from the clipboard into word, not just the text. I've managed to do an RTF text paste but I also need `pictures/links/etc`. The data I'm copying is from a website, and the program needs to paste it exactly as if I'm hitting <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> into the document.

From what I understand, the clipboard will hold a DataObject, and I can't seem to find a way to get that into a word document.

I don't care if `doc` or `docx` is used. Either is fine.

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried sofar?

Comment: @varocarbas I'm currently just using Novacode:
var doc = DocX.Create(docLocation);
doc.InsertParagraph(Clipboard.GetText());

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any experience in this specific library. I have added the corresponding tag to help experienced-on-this answerers find your question.

Comment: @varocarbas Thank you, though I don't really care what library I have to use to do this.

Comment: If you don't care about the specific library you should try others (or rely on in-built funcionalities, like Interop.Word). You should perhaps try a bit harder than just writing a couple of lines of code. For example, just by relying on Clipboard you have quite a few options (GetData, GetDataObject, etc.).

Comment: You should [edit] and add details about what you're doing (expand a bit on your comment). Your question looks off topic without it.

Comment: Don't use Novacode-docx for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @phillip What would you recommend using?

Comment: @varocarbas Clipboard is the only way to get the data in the proper formatting. I have tried several other libraries but haven't been able to find something that can place a data object (acquired by Clipboard.GetDataObject()) into a Word document.

Comment: @will I'm not sure what else to add - I've changed the title to "Paste DataObject Into Word" because that's what I'm attempting to do. Does that work?

Comment: See? Doing some tests/research rather than asking each single bit is a more efficient proceeding to get what you want. Additionally, the code you wrote now is much closer to the minimum requirements to ask in SO (your previous two lines were almost nothing). Accept your own answer as the right one and enjoy your new knowledge.

Comment: @varocarbas I had searched around for a good two hours before asking a question. I had tried with OpenXML and Novacode, and had a bunch of failed code that didn't work in C#, so I didn't include it. I understand there's a lot of questions that come in here that have no previous effort in them, this is not one of them. I just didn't have anything to show after the amount of failures.

I can't accept my own answer quite yet. I will do it when I can.

Comment: Happy to read that. Not sure why you cannot accept your own question yet; I think that it is a worthy answer to this question. The code is a bit incomplete, but good enough for what was asked.

Comment: @varocarbas Told me I had to wait 24 hours. I had 13 minutes left when I replied. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word:

```
                    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                    object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
                    Word._Application oWord;
                    Word._Document oDoc;
                    oWord = new Word.Application();
                    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    Word.Paragraph oPara1;
                    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
                    oPara1.Range.Paste();
                    oDoc.SaveAs(docOutput);
```